# Multiple time executing cell paint event in datagridview view (Winform)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I wanted to keep a functionality like search and highlight the data row cell content in datagridview row.

I am using cellpaint event for the same.

I am setting search matching cell content again and that time on event am highlighting the cell.

I would need a suggestion whether any alternative event can be used for the same purpose. because I have noticed that the event is executing for all cells, above a cell the modified cell.

below is my code snaps

```
//re setting cell content to highlight
 dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value = "";
 dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value = "test";

 void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
 {
 //highliting here if match search content
 }
```

Comment: You can color a cell directly: `dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;`. Don't forget to store the index so you can reset the cell! -  Or you can use the CellPainting event. Yes it is called fo each Cell, but that is no problem at all. If you should ever see flicker (and you won't) you could use a Doublebufferd DGV-subclass.. Of course you will check the row- and columindex in the cellpaint event and only do something when they math the right cell..

Comment: Taw I want to color only a part of the cell, if cell text is Google and search string is goo, only that part need to be color

Comment: OK, for this the CellPainting event is the way to go. Don't try to optimize before you actually have a problem!! (Google ['premature optimization'](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) !) The event is called internally for each cell anyway..

Comment: I have done as your comment, it is working perfect now @TaW